# Make vim commands be executed once a job on a terminal buffer has finished

Tags: key-bindings, terminal-buffer, filetype-c++, job-control

## The context

I've the following mapping in `~/.vim/ftplugin/cpp/mappings.vim`. What this mapping does is to compile an arbitrary C++ file and open two windows `(a)` and `(b)`. `(a)` shows the output of the compiler and `(b)` shows the output of executing the resulting binary file.

```
01| fun! MyCPPFunction()
02|     sil wa
03| 
04|     let l:file = expand("%")
05| 
06|     exe "term g++ -Wunused-variable " . l:file
07|     exe "term ./a.out"
08| endfun
09| 
10| nnoremap <silent> <buffer> <c-p> :call MyCPPFunction()<CR>
```

There is no problem with this approach but I would like to make the buffer, which shows the compiler output, to be closed or not be opened if it is empty since opening an empty buffer is a nuisance.

Specifically,

- If line 6 were to create an empty buffer (implies no errors and no warnings from the compiler), then close it or don't open it and execute line 7.
- If line 6 were to create a nonempty buffer (implies errors or warnings from the compiler), then don't execute line 7.

Because of this, it is demandatory that line 6 finishes in order to execute command from line 7. However, line 7 is executed without waiting for line 6 to finish.

## The question

So my question is: How can I implement this feature to my function? I'm currently reading the documentation on functions related to the `:term` command (`term_start()`, `job_start()`), but I haven't found something that might help me accomplish this.

Note that this would be easily accomplished if we were able to specify which function to execute once the job on a terminal buffer has finished. Thus, we would need to pass the number of lines in the current buffer, and execute the binary file if the number of lines equals 0.

*PD1*: I wrote the function using the `term` command because thus the output of both the compiler (line 6) and my program (line 7) is opened in a vim buffer which implies that I have all features that can be performed on a buffer (diff, regex search, copy, make changes, etc.)

Comment: Check `:h exit_cb`.

Comment: You should probably use `:make` to build your program, not `:term`